# LNK1181 error says it can't find an object in a debug dir but I'm building a release

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

In vs 2017, in c++.  Building Debug config works but fails linking on release mode looking for a debug obj

My vs2017 solution has two c++ projects
1) findcircles -  a DLL (includes utils.cpp to build)
2) findcirclestest - A console test app to call/test the dll.

As per the error messages shown below, even though I'm building the solution in configuration mode, the only the release build of findcirclestest fails ,linking error LNK1181, referencing the utils.obj BUT IN THE DLL project's **DEBUG** DIR (vs the release dir).

As the output shows, it knows it's building the Release mode of findcirclestest.  The VC++/Library Directories specifies the release (and NOT the Dedbug dir) C:\findcircles\findcircles\x64\Release

The Solution property pages seem to be correct specifying Relese configs for both projects (when the Solution is Axctive(Release)).  The project dependencies show the findcirclestest being dependent on findcircles.

2>------ Build started: Project: findcirclestest, Configuration: Release x64 ------
....
2>LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file '....\findcircles\findcircles\x64\Debug\utils.obj'

Comment: Make sure you are linking with the release version of the library in release mode. I think you are linking with the debug import library in release mode.

Comment: Also you may want to try to completely delete the Debug and Release folders in explorer and do a clean build.

Comment: Other than what I said above the project files are xml files. You can look through the release section to see if something does not make sense.